# Choose an index set to make a multiplier

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, ergodic-theory

Fix $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Let $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k\in\left\{1,2,\cdots, k-1\right\}$.

I'm looking for an algorithm to choose an index set $I\subset\left\{1,2,\cdots,k\right\}$ such that $$\sum_{i\in I}a_i=k\cdot N $$ for some integer $N$.

I guess there must be a such index. Is there an good algorithm to be recommended?

Comment: Is this a contest question?

Comment: Is $N$ a given integer? That is, is it an input for the algorithm?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti No. I've got here solving a combinatorics problem.

Comment: @ajotatxe No $N$ is not give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that
$$
a_{1}, a_{1} + a_{2}, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^{t} a_{i}, \dots, a_{1} + a_{2} + \dots + a_{k}
$$
are $k$ (not necessarily) distinct numbers. If they have distinct remainders when divided by $k$, then one of the remainders will have to be zero, so that particular sum, say $\sum_{i=1}^{t_{0}} a_{i}$ will be divisible by $k$.

If the remainders are not distinct, we will have for some $t_{0} < t_{1}$ amd some $q_{0}, q_{1}$ and $0 \le r < k$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{t_{0}} a_{i} 
=
q_{0} k + r
=
q_{1} k + r
=
\sum_{i=1}^{t_{1}} a_{i},
$$
hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{t_{1}} a_{i}
-
\sum_{i=1}^{t_{0}} a_{i}
=
\sum_{i=t_{0} + 1}^{t_{1}} a_{i}
=
(q_{1} - q_{0}) k
$$
is divisible by $k$,

Comment: Oh good. Thanks!